# Antlr4, mismatched input error: the token is not recognized

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I have the following ANTLR grammar:

```
declareField : MODIFIER* typeVar nameType ASSIGN value ';';
nameType : NAME(('.')NAME)*;
typeVar : nameType | nameType'<'typeVar'>' | typeVar'['']';
value : PRIMITIVE_VALUE;
```

And such a set of tokens:

```
ASSIGN : '=';

NULL : 'null';
INT : [0-9]+;
FLOAT : [0-9]+.[0-9]+;
STRING : '"'[a-zA-Z_0-9.]*'"';
CHAR : '\''[a-zA-Z_0-9]'\'';
BOOLEAN : TRUE | FALSE;
TRUE : 'true';
FALSE : 'false';

PRIMITIVE_VALUE : INT | FLOAT | STRING | CHAR | BOOLEAN | NULL;

PUBLIC : 'public';
PRIVATE : 'private';
FINAL : 'final';
STATIC : 'static';
VOLATILE : 'volatile';
TRANSIENT : 'transient';
SYNCHRONIZED : 'synchronized';
NATIVE : 'native';
ABSTRACT : 'abstract';
PROTECTED : 'protected';

MODIFIER : PUBLIC | PRIVATE | FINAL | STATIC | VOLATILE | TRANSIENT | SYNCHRONIZED | NATIVE | ABSTRACT | PROTECTED;

NAME : [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*;
WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

I expected such input data will be accepted by my grammar:

```
protected static final int test = 10;
```

But I get the following error.

```
line 1:0 mismatched input 'protected' expecting {MODIFIER, NAME}
```

Although the token `'protected'` should definitely be accepted by the rule `MODIFIER`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule `MODIFIER` will never match because all the rules a `MODIFIER` is made from are matched before `MODIFIER`.

Change it to be a parser rule instead:

```
declareField : modifier* typeVar nameType ASSIGN value ';';

...

modifier : PUBLIC | PRIVATE | FINAL | STATIC | VOLATILE | TRANSIENT | SYNCHRONIZED | NATIVE | ABSTRACT | PROTECTED;

PUBLIC : 'public';
PRIVATE : 'private';
FINAL : 'final';
STATIC : 'static';
VOLATILE : 'volatile';
TRANSIENT : 'transient';
SYNCHRONIZED : 'synchronized';
NATIVE : 'native';
ABSTRACT : 'abstract';
PROTECTED : 'protected';
```